# PyTorch Sparse Tensors number of dimensions must be nDimI + nDimV

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

I'm trying to insert the value in `gd` to coordinate `[1,0]`. Below are the matrices. When I try this, I get a RuntimeError.

```
>>> import torch
>>> cd = [[1, 0]]
>>> gd = [0.39613232016563416]
>>> i = torch.LongTensor(cd)
>>> v = torch.FloatTensor(gd)
>>> p = torch.rand(2)
>>> i

 1  0
[torch.LongTensor of size 1x2]

>>> v

 0.3961
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1]

>>> p

 0.4678
 0.0996
[torch.FloatTensor of size 2]

>>> torch.sparse.FloatTensor(i.t(), v, torch.Size(list(p.size()))).to_dense()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: invalid argument 2: number of dimensions must be nDimI + nDimV at /Users/soumith/code/builder/wheel/pytorch-src/torch/lib/THS/generic/THSTensor.c:169
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

1) Right now `p` is a Tensor of rank 1. To insert something in position `[1,0]` it needs to be a Tensor of rank 2.

2) You don't need to do complicated things with sparse tensors. Simply `p[cd[0], cd[1]] = v[0]` should work. Where `cd = torch.LongTensor([row_idx, col_idx])`

So:

```
>>> cd = torch.LongTensor([1,0])
>>> gd = [0.39613232016563416]
>>> v = torch.FloatTensor(gd)
>>> p = torch.rand((2,2))
>>> p
```

> ```
>  0.9342  0.8539
>  0.7044  0.0823
> ```
>
> [torch.FloatTensor of size 2x2]

```
>>> p[cd[0], cd[1]] = v[0]
>>> p
```

> ```
> 0.9342  0.8539
> 0.3961  0.0823
> ```
>
> [torch.FloatTensor of size 2x2]

That simple.

Comment: Turned out that the issue was that `p.size()` gave `(2L,)` and `len((2L,))` is 1  like you pointed out, so I just added an if block to ensure that the size will always be two e.g. `s = list(p.size())` and then `if len(s) == 1: s.append(1)` so that I can accept any shaped tensor that I would expect from a neuralnet.